# Phonegap Android application infinite pop up error in Android 2.2 but not in Android 4.0.3

Tags: jquery, android, cordova, android-2.2-froyo, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I'm working on a HTML5 + jQuery app for Android using phonegap. When I test it on an Android 4.0.3 device it works fine, but in Android 2.2 I get infinite gap_poll pop up messages.

Anyone knows how to solve this?

Comment: Are you using PhoneGap Build?

Comment: @mccrager No, I'm building it in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came around this. I had to put the domain of the remote server I where the app I was calling is located on the whitelist on the cordova.xml file.